# R - Overlaying bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe like this (sorry for the long code)

```
set.seed(23) 
date_list = seq(1:30)
testframe1 = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe1$ABC = rnorm(30)

testframe2 = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe2$DEF = rnorm(30)

testframe3 = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe3$GHI = rnorm(30)

testframe4 = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe4$JKL = rnorm(30)

testlist = list(testframe1, testframe2, testframe3, testframe4)
names(testlist) = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")

library(tidyverse)
testlist = testlist %>% reduce(left_join, by = "Date")

library(reshape2)
testlist <- melt(testlist,id.vars = "Date")
```

I want to create a barplot and I tried this, that gave me the following plot:

```
ggplot(testlist, aes(fill = variable, y = value, x = Date)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]
But this is not really what I need. I dont want the bars to add up, I want them to overlay. So that the variable with the highest value is overlaid by the 2nd highest and so on, until the smallest value.

Is there an easy way to fix that? I only find help for stacked barplots, but thats not what I need.

Comment: Have you tried `position = "dodge"`?

Comment: Where do I have to add this?

Comment: ggplot(testlist, aes(fill = variable, y = value, x = Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") gives me this error: Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

Comment: Ok, I tired: ggplot(testlist, aes(fill = variable, y = value, x = Date)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge")
, but that is still not what I need. I want them to really overlay over each other.

Comment: Yes thanks! That is what I wanted! But it would be great not to use an alpha, just to order them from highest to lowest.

Comment: Ok, I see. I really thought there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: If I'm missing something and there's a way to do that someone will comment on it and we'll both find out :)

Comment: @AntoniosK, you can also achieve what you did there with `position = "identity"`, like this: `ggplot(testlist, aes(fill = variable, y = value, x = Date)) + 
  geom_bar(stat= "identity", position="identity", alpha = 0.6)`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right! `position="identity"` is the key here. I completely forgot about it :D

Comment: @Mr.Spock I think @Sven has provided exactly what you want in a much shorter / better version :) You can also use the `geom_col` alternative like this: `ggplot(testlist, aes(fill = variable, y = value, x = Date)) + 
  geom_col(position = "identity", alpha = 0.3)`. The `position = "identity"` will make sure that the bars will fall onto each other and will give you the "overlay" format you wanted. You will still need the `alpha = ` though...

Comment: Thanks! That already looks really good! Can I maybe assign the colors manually?

Comment: @Mr.Spock, yes you can. Take a look at `scale_fill_manual()`